# For loop keeps on going how do I stop it?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to add up the scores. In the example I inserted I wanted the answers 3,5,7 which I received at the beginning. However, it keeps on going which results in me getting the wrong answer. What is it that I do wrong?

Here is my code:

```
def score(pins):

    result=[]
    for i in range(len(pins) -1):
        if pins[0] + pins[1] != 10:
            result.append(sum([pins[0]] + [pins[1]]))
            print(result)
            score(pins[1:])
    return result
```

And the result I get for `score([1,2,3,4])` is:

```
[3]
[5]
[7]
[5, 5]
[7]
[3, 3]
[5]
[7]
[5, 5]
[7]
[3, 3, 3]
[5]
[7]
[5, 5]
[7]
[3, 3, 3]
```

The result I wanted was `[3,5,7]` but I get `[3,3,3]`. What is it that I do wrong?

Comment: Kindly add the code and output into the question instead giving the snapshot

Comment: For one thing, your recursive call has no effect. `score` simply returns something. Also, you are trying to do the same thing with recursion and a for loop. A simple for loop would be better for this.

Comment: removing score(pins[1:]) helped. However I'm still getting the wrong result. I get : [3]
[3, 3]
[3, 3, 3]
[3, 3, 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mainly because you are mixing for loops and recursion.

```
def score(pins):

    result=[]
    for i in range(len(pins) -1):
        if pins[0] + pins[1] != 10:
            result.append(sum([pins[0]] + [pins[1]]))
            print(result)
            score(pins[1:])
    return result
```

As you can see, your code first uses a for loop that iterates over the list, which is correct. However, you do not use your variable "i" and proceeds to do a recursive implementation. However, you do nothing with the eventual output of "score(pins[1:])", so what happens in you append the sum of the first two terms of the list len(scores)-1 times, which is 3.

This would be an implementation using for loops.

```
>>> def scores(pins):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(pins)-1):
        if pins[i] + pins[i+1] != 10:
            result.append(pins[i] + pins[i+1])
    return result

>>> scores([1,2,3,4])
[3, 5, 7]
```

(Just a side note here, `sum([pins[0]] + [pins[1]])` isn't necessary. `pins[i] + pins[i+1]` achieves the same effect).

Answer (score 0):

Simply try my One Linear for loop:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4]
scores = [sum(mylist[i:i+2]) for i in range(len(mylist)-1)]
print(scores) # output: [3,5,7]
```